# Can anyone see why this Intent isnt being picked up?

Tags: android

```
//Create intent 

notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        note = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, contentText, System.currentTimeMillis() );

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
notificationIntent.putExtra("aff_id",aff_id);
notificationIntent.setAction("com.mindfsck.PossAff.aff");

notificationIntent =  notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, aff_id, notificationIntent, 0);
note.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, title, aff_id + contentText, contentIntent);

notificationManager.notify(aff_id,note);

//Pickup intent 

package com.mindfsck.PossAff;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

public class PosAffIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.mindfsck.PossAff.aff")) {
            System.out.println("Picked up broadcast with aff");
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, com.mindfsck.PossAff.MainActivity.class));
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){        

        }

        System.out.println("Picked up broadcast");
    }
}

//Manifest
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".PosAffIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <!--<action android:name="com.mindfsck.PossAff.intent.action.aff"></action> -->
            <action android:name="com.mindfsck.PossAff.aff"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".NotificationAlarm">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

I see the following in the Debug monitor when I click the notification

03-04 11:00:24.652: INFO/ActivityManager(1296): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.mindfsck.PossAff.aff flg=0x200000 (has extras) }

but it never gets picked up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed: 
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, aff_id, notificationIntent, 0);

To 
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.**getBroadcast**(ctx, aff_id, notificationIntent, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Missing the DEFAULT category in the intent filter in your manifest? (Assuming I understand what you mean with "never gets picked up" correctly).

Comment: What I mean is onReceive in PosAffIntentReceiver is never called